# VB.Net to C# conversion of '+' operator

Tags: c#, vb.net

Why VB.Net converts this code

```
Sub Main()
    Dim str As String = ""
    Dim lNumber As Integer = 0
    str = "String " + lNumber
    Console.WriteLine(str)
End Sub
```

to

```
public static void Main()
{
    int lNumber = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(Conversions.ToString((double) (Conversions.ToDouble("String ") + lNumber)));
}
```

Instead of just

```
public static void Main()
{
    int lNumber = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("String " + lNumber);
}
```

I am asking this as in C#

> When one or both operands are of type string, + concatenates the string representations of the operands

Comment: How are you converting this? I have just use this http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=01dcb8e4-3e6d-4d89-ae01-817dc388e243. and it generates the same result as you want.

Comment: Simply because `operator+` does not have the same semantics across both languages.

Comment: @Sachin I am Disassembling the code using Red Gate's .Net reflector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**VB.NET +***
VB.NET sees operator `+` as an arithmatic operator, try to add one number to another number. If one operand is a number, it converts the other operand to a number (but only if `Option Explicit` is `On`). Only if both operands are strings, those strings will be concatinated.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9c5t70w2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

**VB.NET &***
VB.NET sees operator `&` as an operator to concatinate strings. If one operand is a string, it converts the other operand to a string.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wfx50zyk(v=vs.80).aspx

**C#.NET +***
C#.NET sees operator `+`, depending on the datatypes, as an arithmatic operator of concatination operator. If one operand is a string, it converts the other operand to a string.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz(v=vs.71).aspx

So knowing this, it is logical that the VB.NET operator + is converted into methods to convert the operands to numbers.

To see all differences between the language, see: http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

Comment: Yes... my text was not entierly complete. It says: if ONE opererand is a number... That does not state anything for two strings. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to my question [here (+ Operator (Visual Basic) )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9c5t70w2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**Data types of expressions**: What happens when One expression is a numeric data type and the other is a string?

**Action by compiler**: If Option Strict is On, then generate a compiler error.
If Option Strict is Off, then implicitly convert the String to Double and add.
If the String cannot be converted to Double, then throw an InvalidCastException exception.